# JS, when a variable is assigned to another variable, does it hold a reference to that variable or the value that that variable holds at that moment?

Tags: javascript, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

Provided this code

```js
let myVar = 'hey'
let myVar2 = myVar
myVar = 'what'
```

When I assign `let myVar2 = myVar`, I am assigning a reference to `myVar2`? Or in the assignation `myVar` gets resolved and I am assigning the value that `myVar` has at that moment?

My doubt is whether

- `myVar2` holds a reference towards the original `myVar` (which is no longer available since it has been overwritten by the second assignation `myVar = 'what'`)
- or `myVar2` holds since the beginning whatever value had `myVar`, regardless that that variable will be overwritten later on

Comment: It's always pass by value. `myVar` and `myVar2` never held literally each other. Just content that happens to be similar.

Comment: ...however the "value" of a variable that "holds" an array or object is always actually a _reference_ to that object. This reference itself is still handled as a value though, it's not a reference to the previous variable but a reference to the object itself. So: `myVar = {a: 1}; myVar2 = myVar; console.log(myVar === myVar2) /* true */; myVar2.b = 2; console.log(myVar) /* {a: 1, b: 2} */; myVar2 = 'abc'; console.log(myVar) /* {a: 1, b: 2} */;`

Comment: strings, numbers, booleans, null = value. objects, arrays = reference. undefined is just weird (you can argue it either way - older versions of javascript like the one running on IE7 or Netscape4 would definitely be reference. Newer versions of javascript made undefined immutable)

Comment: @slebetman The `undefined` value is and always was immutable. (Sure, `window.undefined` could be overwritten, but that did not change the value of any variables).

Comment: @CherryDT Even with objects, the variable always holds a reference *value* which references that object. The variable never becomes or holds a reference to another variable.

Comment: Yes, this is why I wrote "This reference itself is still handled as a value though, it's not a reference to the previous variable but a reference to the object itself." in my comment... I just added a clarification because as a beginner it may be confusing to then see objects being mutated.